# Suggestion needed regarding performance of stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, stored-functions

We have an application which needs to write data to a particular table in oracle DBMS. But before writing to the table it do certain manipulation on the data it writes.

We are now planning to take this 'manipulation of data' out of the application and delegate this responsibility to a stored procedure in ORACLE DBMS. Their procedure, on other hand, will take help of different in-built and explicitly written functions to do its job.

Now my concern is how efficient is the 'procedure run' in ORACLE DBMS. I am supposing Oracle will invoke different functions call from the stored procedure in an in-line fashion, or otherwise , but will definitely not make those calls as part of some child process, which will otherwise give a big hit to the performance of this stored-procedure.

Note:This procedure will be called through-out the day, with hundreds of thousand of row to be updated. This make the performance of this stored-procedure very crucial for the application.

Can you comment on the performance of the stored procedure in general as compared to when manipulation is part of an application.

EDIT:
Manipulation is as simple as taking few values out from a map, collating them together and update them in a particular column of a table.

Many Thanks,
Mawia

Comment: the overhead should be minimal

Comment: What kind of manipulations are you talking about? Do you have an example?

Comment: It is unreasonable, why this question was closed. It is very much a real question which asking for suggestion, expert comment. It is not necessary that a question has to be end with question mark, for it to be a real question.

Answer (score 3):

The PL/SQL code will access data with lower latency than the application, and you're unlikely to have a problem If you follow good practice's. Do as much as possible in SQL, and use implicit cursors instead of explicit cursors.